Identifying Poorly Forecastable Time Series Using tsfeatures
I am working on a problem involving the identification of poorly forecastable time series using features extracted with the tsfeatures library by Rob J. Hyndman. Below are the key details about my dataset and approach:
Dataset:

Over 140,000 individual time series.

Each time series spans 29 months, with one value per month.

Forecasting horizon: 7 months.


Objective:
Determine which time series are poorly forecastable by leveraging extracted features and evaluating forecast errors.
Current Approach
Step 1: Feature Extraction
Using the tsfeatures library, I calculate various statistical and time series features for each of the 140,000 time series. These features are then stored in a DataFrame for further analysis.
Step 2: Forecasting
Each time series is forecasted using multiple models: TimesNet, NBEATS, NHITS.
These models are optimized, and I compute forecast error metrics for each:

MSE (when scaling the data beforehand).
MAAPE (when data is not scaled).

I record the lowest forecast error value (e.g., min_maape) for each time series in the DataFrame.
Step 3: Preparing the Data for Regression
The DataFrame now contains extracted features and error metrics for each time series.
I create the feature matrix (X_features) by dropping irrelevant or problematic columns, such as:

['unique_id', 'ds', 'y', 'hurst', 'arch_acf', 'garch_acf', 'arch_r2', 'garch_r2', 'min_maape', 'max_maape', 'TimesNet', 'NHITS', 'NBEATSx']

The target variable (y_maape) contains the minimum MAAPE values:

y_maape = feature_evaluation_merged['min_maape']

I perform an 80/20 train-test split:
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, unique_ids_train, unique_ids_test = train_test_split(
X_features, y_maape, unique_ids, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)


Step 4: Training Regressors
I train various regressors to predict min_maape based on the extracted features. So far, I’ve tested:

Random Forest
Decision Tree
Gradient Boosting
Ensemble Models combining Random Forest, Gradient Boosting, and AdaBoost

Example of training a Random Forest Regressor:
rf = RandomForestRegressor(
max_depth=9,
min_samples_leaf=10,
min_samples_split=9,
n_estimators=743,
random_state=42
)
rf.fit(X_train_numeric, y_train)
Step 5: Hyperparameter Optimization
I optimized the regressors using:

Optuna Framework
GridSearchCV from scikit-learn

Step 6: Evaluation
The predicted values (e.g., rf.predict(X_test)) remain between 0.6 and 1.0, regardless of the regressor used or the extent of optimization. Here are two examples:
Predicted Values Distribution:

MAAPE Difference (True vs. Predicted Values):

Questions:

Does my method make sense?
Despite hyperparameter optimization, the predicted values remain in a narrow range (0.6–1.0). How can I improve this?
Are there methodological flaws, missed steps, or potential improvements I could incorporate?

Thank you in advance for your insights!

(1) What is the MAAPE? Percentage errors have issues. (2) I would argue (Kolassa, 2020) that it does not make sense to look at multiple error measures for a single forecast, and your forecasting models likely aim for an expectation forecast, so you should really look at the (R)MSE. How big a problem that is will depend on your time series.

(3) What kind of "improvement" are you looking for when you are unhappy that the predicted MAAPEs are in a "narrow" range? This may be relevant.

@StephanKolassa (1)  It is a variation of the traditional Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE), but with a significant improvement in how it handles extreme values and errors around zero. (3) Im trying to get a way to get as many values on the ideal fit line so i can actually see if there are timeseries that always have a bad value, so i can extract the feature values of those to explain why and which time series are poorly forecastable.
Thank you for the infos and links already, i appreciate that alot!

Ah, I assume the MAAPE is from Kim & Kim (2016)? I'm not sure I would call that an improvement... it's an error measure that elicits a different functional from the predictive distribution. At least this functional is defined. But the question still remains whether this functional is what you want. See that 2020 paper of mine. And yes, this is a digression.

Incidentally, I put up Q&A for "optimal" point forecasts for lognormally and gamma distributed actuals, where "optimal" of course refers to one specific error measure. I did not include the MAAPE in my lists of error measures (and I don't immediately see analytical solutions). But it's easy to simulate, say, lognormal data with log-mean 0 and log-SD 1 (so the mean of the actuals will be 1.69 and the variance 5.80) and numerically find that the MAAPE-optimal forecast is 0.54, far below the mean.


Despite hyperparameter optimization, the predicted values remain in a narrow range (0.6–1.0). How can I improve this?
I'm trying to get a way to get as many values on the ideal fit line

The question really is whether the variation in the MAAPE (or any other target variable) is signal or noise, so whether this is forecastable: Regression predictions show far less variance than expected. Your scatterplot is very consistent with there being some signal (which accounts for the variation in the predicted MAAPE, and the positive correlation between the predicted and the actual), but also a lot of residual noise (which accounts for there being more variation in the actual than in the predicted MAAPE).
Determining whether something - your MAAPE, or anything else - is forecastable or not is hard: How to know that your machine learning problem is hopeless? And to be honest, your situation does not fill me with hope. If you have only 29 monthly values, and actually set aside the last 7 for holdout testing (I assume you only calculate your features on the first 22, yes?), you simply do not have a lot of data to extract features to be able to forecast this particular series' MAAPE.
You may be able to do something if you can include master data features from your series - after all, your time series come from somewhere, so they have some sort of context, like a product hierarchy or something, and I would definitely look to this context to enrich your MAAPE prediction.
However, in any case, your histories are just very short, and there is not all that much you will be able to do. I would recommend that you accept that your MAAPE prediction may not be as good as you would like it to be, regardless of how much effort you invest.

To clarify: I calculate the features based on 29 months of data and then use another 7 months for testing, resulting in a total of 36 months or 3 years. My supervisor and I thought this would be sufficient for a good prediction.
I’m still a student and relatively new to the whole time series and forecasting topic.
If I understood correctly, first, MAAPE is not an ideal measure for this type of problem, and second, having more months of data could improve the prediction.
The time series data consists of sales figures from different companies, but they are anonymized.

OK, thanks, that is helpful. 29 months of history does sound more reasonable than 22 months (to be precise: 32% more reasonable), but there will still be a limit to forecastability of the MAAPE - especially if all you have are the time series. I am not saying that the MAAPE is inappropriate, I am saying that it elicits a functional of the time series that you may or may not want. I understand requiring an expectation forecast (which you elicit using the MSE) or a quantile (use a pinball loss). I have never seen a case where I would want the MAAPE-optimal forecast. YMMV.
